# Is it possible for Devil to use Steadfast effectively?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I may have made a mistake in giving the Devil of Caroc the soulbound item Steadfast, as its level 3 requires getting to 30 might.

The Devil starts with 13 base might, I can give it +3 from resting at Caed Nua, and +3 from one of the helms I found, bringing me to 19. From here, I can give myself +10 via the priest buff Champion's Boon. This brings me to a running total of 29.

Since the Devil can't eat food, use drugs, or drink potions, what can I do to get that extra point of might?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a + 4 might helm in game, from one of the white march part 2 bounty quests.

You can get the helm by doing the bounty "Magran's Faithful" which is gotten by talking to Asca in Stalwart. Asca is near the fisheries, on the left side.